# jquery: Can I use the enabled and disabled pseudo-selectors with the css method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an add-on that I want to style dynamically, one way for dark mode and the other for light mode.

I tried using `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {` but this was ignored in both Firefox and Chrome when the user had a dark mode. You need to fiddle with a config setting to trigger this, and that's out of the comfort zone of many of the add-on's users.

Instead, I'm using JS to determine the background and text colors for the main text fields using `browser.theme.getCurrent()` (not currently supported in Chrome (do they ever update their API?)), and if the result has a popup field that defines a dark color (which I set as one where at least 2 of the 3 colors have a value < 255/3), I dynamically style the various parts of my widget accordingly. Otherwise I continue to use the styles from the .css file.

However, I can't determine which buttons are disabled. The following code has no effect

```
$('button:disabled').css('color', '#2a2a2e');
// or
$('button[disabled]').css('color', '#2a2a2e');
// or using the class name
$('.myButtonClass:disabled').css('color', '#2a2a2e');
```

If I dump the following results, I get values that make sense:

```
  console.log("# total buttons:" + $('.button').length);
  console.log("# enabled buttons:" + $('.button:enabled').length);
  console.log("# disabled buttons:" + $('.button:disabled').length);
```

But there seems to be a problem setting CSS directives with this value.
Is this a limitation in JS, a bug in jquery, or am I doing something wrong (which
I've been known to do in the past)?

Comment: Can you perhaps create a small snippet that demonstrates the problem? I do notice that in your first piece of code you use `$('button:disabled')` but in the working piece you are using `$('.button:disabled')` note class, not tag selector

Comment: Both `$('button:disabled')` and `$('.button:disabled')` failed to work.  As for a small snippet, that's tough to do for a firefox extension. The full code in question is at https://github.com/ericpromislow/tabhunter/blob/243131c89f3cbbc21ec955d0a17e74182464699b/popup/tabhunter.js.erb#L286

Comment: I'm also thinking of setting the style on each button as I update its disabled status, but I prefer the declarative approach.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely should be possible to make it work this way...

Comment: Or even better, move the JS code back to CSS with a "dark" class attribute, and add the attr dynamically.